# How do you create cascading drop-down lists in Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I am selecting an item from a drop down list, then based on the selected item, how would I display another drop down list? For example, in the code below, if I select option "india" I want to display another drop down box containing 2-3 state names.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function india()
    {
        var x =document.getElementById('con').value;
        alert(x);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id='h1'> first </h1>
    <select id="con" onchange="indai()"> 
        <option>----select----</option>
        <option value="india" >India</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is fairly common if you look on GOOGLE you should be able to find an example of code. Than if you encounter an error you should go back to step one and look on GOOGLE. If your Google search is not fixing your issue than post the code your have tried, the error you got and your question exemple: Hi, I have this error code with this code (some code here) could anyone point out where I am derping please? Than we will gladly help.

Comment: As for now I am on the impression that all you want is for us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7FtkS/

This is a good solution.

```
onchange="document[value](value)"

// where the [value] defines the name of the function and (value) used as id-parm
document.india = function(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='';
}
```